# How can I make sure when i swipe my view changes in android

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, layout

I want one part of the view to look like this when i swipe, and when i swipe to the other side it should do the reverse. How can i achieve this in Kotlin?

When i swipe male text and image is bigger and the female image and textview is on the other side. Can i achieve this with cardviews and creating 2 different layouts?

[image]

Comment: Give MotionLayout a try: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/animations/motionlayout